# Show multiple data fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal Reports and need a lot of help here. I'm trying to create a monthly report showing information for each day. I need to be able to display all the field for each individual record for each day of that specific month.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: how many fields and what is individual record? need more info to help

Comment: There are about 25 fields. Each record is data from a single day. I need to be able to display data for each day in a month on one page.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below process.

1. Place all 25 fields on the report in detail section.
2. Group according to date for a single day.
3. Take summary of 25 fields on the group footer and supress details poart.
4. Run the report you have 1 record for 1 day for data that is retrived from database.

Comment: I'm completely new to Crystal Reports, but what you're saying is that I use the Group Footer to display all of the records instead of the details part?

Comment: yes if you are not getting by records from database. if records from database are by monthly then you can directly display in detail part